# Javascript in console or CLI?

Tags: javascript, command-line, cmd

When someone says they are running "code.js" in console or cli, what exactly does that mean? What do I need to make command line execute my .js files locally?

WindowsOS

Comment: Are you asking what a command line interface is? Or are you looking for people to recommend a JavaScript compiler that can run on your CLI (for whatever operating system you neglected to mention you were using)?  (Shopping questions are off-topic BTW).

Comment: How does this get an upvote?? who did this? Please read [ask]. Questions like this should not be encouraged

Comment: Depends on the OS and type of applications you have. Windows Scripting Host for example is able to execute JavaScript

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To run Javascript "in console", you simply open the developer tools in your favourite browser and open the "console" window. This gives you access to the Javascript environment of the current page.

To run Javascript in your CLI, you need a Javascript interpreter. Both [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) and [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) provide interpreters which can be used from the command-line of all modern systems. (Of the two, NodeJS is much more popular for standalone applications written in Javascript, and Rhino is more popular for embedding Javascript in other applications.)

Comment: Driveby downvotes: explain? What I've said here is correct, and a reasonable answer to the OP.

Comment: Seems like there are a lot of pretentious attitudes floating about here and it doesn't embody a very inviting feel. I've tried to credit you with the correct answer

Comment: Thanks! We all need to find the actual terms to Google before we can meaningfully answer our own questions. There's a huge community around Node, so if you're interested in using Javascript as a command-line scripting language, that's what you should check out.

If you're just trying to debug Javascript in web pages, [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) will help you find the console in whatever browser you use.